# find filename regular expression

Tags: shell

I have a file called a_b

I use the following regular expressions to find it, and they work:

```
find . -iname "a_b"

find . -iname "a_*b"
```

But how come the below format does not find it?

```
find . -iname "a_{1}b"
```

Is not correct that `{1}` means the previous character which is `"_"` should match exactly one time ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You are using a *regular expression*, but `find`'s `-iname` and `-name` actions expect *patterns* (globs)**.

[Patterns (globs)](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/globbingref.html) (link courtesy of @Adam) are only distantly related to regular expressions and simpler, but also less powerful.

(As an aside: in your specific example, you need *neither* - just using the character as is will do.)

**If you need the power of a regular expression and your `find` version supports it, use the `-iregex` or `-regex` actions** (they're *not* part of the POSIX standard):

- **GNU `find`** (Linux):

  ```
  find . -regextype posix-extended -iregex ".*/a_{1}b"
  ```
- **FreeBSD/OSX `find`**:

  ```
  find -E . -iregex ".*/a_{1}b"
  ```

Note:

- **`-iregex` and `-regex` match the *entire* input path**, hence the `.*/` prefix.
  (By contrast, `-iname` and `-name` match only the *filename* part.)
- Both snippets **use options to explicitly activate support for *extended* regular expressions** (`-E` / `-regextype posix-extended`) so as to ensure support for constructs such as `{1}` or to allow their use without needing to `\`- escape `{` and `}`.

Comment: [This page](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/globbingref.html) has more information on 'Globbing', and how it is different from a regex.

Comment: Oh! At least now I know I should not put regular expression in front of find! But I typed your suggested solution, and still did not get the results. Could it be my shell lacks regex ?

Comment: @MahshidZeinaly: My bad - please see my updated answer. (As an aside: it's not the _shell_ that matters here, but what the `find` utility supports. What platform are you on?)